# Sqlalchemy-Marshmallow - Nested field not displaying any data

Tags: sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I was having no problem using nested fields in my flask app when using marshmallow-sqlalchemy with Flask-SQLAlchemy. Now that I've switched from Flask-SQLAlchemy to just SQLAlchemy (for a few irrelevant reasons), my nested fields are no longer displaying any data. I feel as though this may have something to do with SQLAlchemy Session not being passed into the nested fields.

My project looks like the following:

```
engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
Session = orm.scoped_session(orm.sessionmaker())
Session.configure(bind=engine)    
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class PodcastModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'podcasts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    host = db.Column(db.String(80))
    episodes = relationship(EpisodeModel, backref='episode', lazy='dynamic')

    @classmethod
    def dump(cls, podcast):
        podcast_schema = PodcastSchemaNested()
        podcast_output = podcast_schema.dump(podcast).data
        return podcast_output

class EpisodeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'episodes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    length = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2))    
    podcast_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('podcasts.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

class BaseSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        sqla_session = Session
        ordered = True 

class PodcastSchemaNested(BaseSchema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.Str()
    host = fields.Str()
    episodes = fields.Nested('EpisodeSchema', many=True)

class EpisodeSchema(BaseSchema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.Str() 
    length = fields.Float()
```

And the json output is the following:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Podcast Name",
"host": "Podcast Host",
"episodes": [

]
}
```

I've been struggling on this issue for several hours now and any input as to why the nested fields aren't displaying any data would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have super recent experience with SQLAlchemy, but maybe check all your serialising/dump methods to make sure everything knows how to write itself. It's not clear to me that Episodes can.

Otherwise, here's where I'd start:

- Does your database exist?
- Does your config still point to it correctly?
- Did you run all the database setup?
- Did everything get added and committed to your session?
- Is it only the episode list that isn't being filled?
- Should you be getting only one podcast listing?
- Is there a typo in the file that contains the episode data
  or the podcast data?
- Should some of the requirements (pip installs) change without
  flask (watch for capitalisation)?
- Did you get the latest sqlalchemy? Have you checked the changelog (it does some joins differently etc)

My very old examples have

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind=engine
```

Is metadata relevant?

(I came here via your upwork post and I was curious - not sure if it is any help at all to unstick you). Good luck.

Comment: Ann, thank you for the detailed reply. I'll be using all those bullet points to diagnose the next time I encounter an issue! I determined that this issue was with how I was handling the sessions on each individual model. Because I wasn't using a scoped session for each model, I guess the session was never passed down to each nested field, thus the empty array of data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the nested fields to work by changing my db file from the above to -

```
from common import config
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship, backref


engine = db.create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
```

And on my model methods, where I access and query the db, instead of -

```
@classmethod
def find_by_name(cls, name):
    session = Session()
    episode = session.query(cls).filter_by(name=name).first()  
    session.close()
    return episode
```

I instead don't create a new session and then close it, but rather used the scoped session which is being imported.

```
from common.db.base import Base, session

@classmethod
def find_by_name(cls, name):
    episode = session.query(cls).filter_by(name=name).first()  
    return episode
```

However, I am still unsure if this is going to cause some issues due to this not being the proper way to handle sessions... Gotta continue reading the docs.